# Why does node js give this error and how do I fix this?

Tags: node.js

```
const wCap = new cv.VideoCapture(0); 
var fourcc = cv.VideoWriter.fourcc("MJPG");
var path = 'output.avi';

// Define the codec and create VideoWriter object.The output is stored in 'outpy.avi' file.
const out = new cv.VideoWriter(path, fourcc, 20.0, (640,480), 1);
```

The output for this program is

```
VideoWriter::New - Error: expected argument 3 to be of type Size
```

Comment: `(640,480)` is not what you expect it to be. It's not a tuple and definitely not a `Size` type. It's `480` since you've used [the comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) which returns the last value. You might need `new Size(640,480)` but I'm not sure what the `Size` type is, it might also be `{width:640, height:480}`

Comment: The syntax `(640,480)` in javascript means `ignore 640 and return 480` so your code is the same as `new cv.VideoWriter(path, fourcc, 20.0, 480, 1)`. Now, I'm not sure what the function expects so this is a comment, not an answer but perhaps the fact you pass the number `480` is the reason?

Comment: Just guessing: new Size(640, 480)

Comment: Your code should look like `new cv.VideoWriter(path, fourcc, 20.0,  new cv.Size(640,480), 1);`